# HTML/CSS/JS not displaying correctly on Wordpress website

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm trying to include a simple checkbox feature on my Wordpress page that displays/disappears images when you toggle the checkboxes.  It works just fine outside of the Wordpress environment, but when I put the code into a WP page, only the checkboxes display, but none of the images.  Clicking the checkboxes also doesn't do anything.

I've tried the HTML Snippet and Raw HTML plugins, which didn't help.  So here is my latest attempt, creating a page template.

Here is the page for you to see: http://enchantingthedesert.com/10-photo-analysis/
and the password is: xX2CNFv6

Thanks in advance!  Here's the code:

```
<?php get_header() ?>


<!-- Part 1: Wrap all page content here -->
<section class="wrap">
  <!-- Begin page content -->
<div class="container">

  <div class="row-fluid">

  <html>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Photo Layers Toggling Demo</title>

<style>
  body {
    width:100%; 
  }

  .photo {
      position:absolute;
      display:block;
      left:0;
      top:0;
      width:100%;
      width:864px;
      height:100%;
      clear: both;

  }

  .photo img {
    width: 100%;  
  }

  .hidden {
    display:none; 
  }
  #photoContainer{

    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    clear: both;
  }

</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function initPhotoLayers(){
    console.log("initPhotoLayers running");

    var photosOnPage = $(".photo").length;
    console.log("initPhotoLayers says " + photosOnPage + " photos");

    for(var i=1;i<=photosOnPage;i++){

      var defaultDisplayTemp = $('.photo:nth-child(' + i + ')').data('defaultdisplay');
      console.log("initPhotoLayers saysdefaultDisplayTemp for " + i + " is " + defaultDisplayTemp);

      var currentPhotoDiv = $('.photo:nth-child(' + i + ')');

      if(defaultDisplayTemp == "hide"){
        //fade out photo to hide it
        currentPhotoDiv.fadeTo(0,0);
      } else {
        // fade in photo to show it
        currentPhotoDiv.fadeTo(1000,1);
      }
      // remove display=none in any case
      currentPhotoDiv.toggleClass("hidden");
    }





  }

  function initCheckboxes(){
    console.log("initCheckboxes running");
    $('#overlay_tint') 
      .bind('click',function(event){
        testCheckboxes(this.id);
      });

    $('#overlay_trails')
      .bind('click',function(event){
        testCheckboxes(this.id);
      });

    $('#overlay_placenames')
      .bind('click',function(event){
        testCheckboxes(this.id);
      }); 
    $('#overlay_trailnames')
      .bind('click',function(event){
        testCheckboxes(this.id);
      }); 

  }


  function testCheckboxes(checkbox){

    console.log("testCheckboxes running with checkbox at " + checkbox);

    checkTarget = checkbox.split("_")[1];

    if($("#" + checkbox).prop('checked')){

      console.log(checkbox + " is checked!"); 
      //$("#" + checkTarget).css("visibility","visible");
      $("#" + checkTarget).fadeTo(200,1);

     // true

    } else {

      console.log(checkbox + " is not checked!"); 
      //$("#" + checkTarget).css("visibility","hidden");
      $("#" + checkTarget).fadeTo(200,0);
    }
  }



  /*
var imageNum = 20;

images/Img + imageNum + -base.jpg


photos = {
  ["Img10-base.jpg","base"]
};*/


</script>

<style id="clearly_highlighting_css" type="text/css">/* selection */ html.clearly_highlighting_enabled ::-moz-selection { background: rgba(246, 238, 150, 0.99); } html.clearly_highlighting_enabled ::selection { background: rgba(246, 238, 150, 0.99); } /* cursor */ html.clearly_highlighting_enabled {    /* cursor and hot-spot position -- requires a default cursor, after the URL one */    cursor: url("chrome-extension://pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc/clearly/images/highlight--cursor.png") 14 16, text; } /* highlight tag */ em.clearly_highlight_element {    font-style: inherit !important; font-weight: inherit !important;    background-image: url("chrome-extension://pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc/clearly/images/highlight--yellow.png");    background-repeat: repeat-x; background-position: top left; background-size: 100% 100%; } /* the delete-buttons are positioned relative to this */ em.clearly_highlight_element.clearly_highlight_first { position: relative; } /* delete buttons */ em.clearly_highlight_element a.clearly_highlight_delete_element {    display: none; cursor: pointer;    padding: 0; margin: 0; line-height: 0;    position: absolute; width: 34px; height: 34px; left: -17px; top: -17px;    background-image: url("chrome-extension://pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc/clearly/images/highlight--delete-sprite.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0px 0px; } em.clearly_highlight_element a.clearly_highlight_delete_element:hover { background-position: -34px 0px; } /* retina */ @media (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {    em.clearly_highlight_element { background-image: url("chrome-extension://pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc/clearly/images/highlight--yellow@2x.png"); }    em.clearly_highlight_element a.clearly_highlight_delete_element { background-image: url("chrome-extension://pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc/clearly/images/highlight--delete-sprite@2x.png"); background-size: 68px 34px; } } </style><style>[touch-action="none"]{ -ms-touch-action: none; touch-action: none; }[touch-action="pan-x"]{ -ms-touch-action: pan-x; touch-action: pan-x; }[touch-action="pan-y"]{ -ms-touch-action: pan-y; touch-action: pan-y; }[touch-action="scroll"],[touch-action="pan-x pan-y"],[touch-action="pan-y pan-x"]{ -ms-touch-action: pan-x pan-y; touch-action: pan-x pan-y; }</style>


<body>

<div id="photoContainer">
<div class="photo" style="z-index: 1900; opacity: 1; display: block;" id="placenames" data-defaultdisplay="hide">
  <img src="http://enchantingthedesert.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/10-place-labels.png" data-defaultdisplay="hide" alt="" usemap="#locationMap">
  <map name="locationMap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="192,318,267,350" href="#" alt="berry butte">
    <area shape="rect" coords="195,324,273,345" href="#" alt="berry butte">
    <area shape="rect" coords="289,392,384,414" href="#" alt="horseshoe mesa">
    <area shape="rect" coords="104,426,197,446" href="#" alt="grandview trail">
    <area shape="rect" coords="346,316,458,335" href="#" alt="South Kaibob">
  </map>
</div>
<div class="photo" style="z-index: 900; opacity: 1; display: block;" id="trailnames" data-defaultdisplay="hide"><img src="http://enchantingthedesert.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/10-trail-names.png" alt=""></div>
<div class="photo" style="z-index: 800; opacity: 1; display: block;" id="trails" data-defaultdisplay="hide"><img src="http://enchantingthedesert.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/10-trails.png" alt=""></div>
<div class="photo" style="z-index: 700; opacity: 0; display: block;" id="tint" data-defaultdisplay="hide"><img src="http://enchantingthedesert.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/10-tinting.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div class="photo" style="z-index: 600; opacity: 1; display: block;" id="bw" data-defaultdisplay="show"><img src="http://enchantingthedesert.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/10-bw-photo.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  initCheckboxes();
  initPhotoLayers()
});
</script>

<div style="display:inline; position: block; font-family: Adamina" id="imageControls">

  <form name="toggler">


  Display layers:
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Overlays" value="placenames" id="overlay_placenames">
    Place names</label> &nbsp; 

    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Overlays" value="trails" id="overlay_trails" schecked="">
    Trails</label> &nbsp; 

 <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Overlays" value="trailnames" id="overlay_trailnames" schecked="">
    Trails names</label> &nbsp; 

      <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Overlays" value="tint" id="overlay_tint">
    Tinting</label>

  </form>
</div>

</body>

</html>

</section><!-- Wrap page -->

  </div><!-- Row page -->


  </div><!-- Content page -->

<?php get_footer() ?>
```

Comment: Check the Javascript console: **unslider** and **isotope** cant be found, a js-file gives a 404 response. Validate your HTML: **21 Errors, 2 warning(s)**

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to clear your code. Take a look at the page source and you'll see that it's a complete mess: you've got there "page inside page" (nested `<html>` tags), jQuery lib is called two times (one outside the `<header>`).

Try to clear the html code to make it standard-compliant, remove that unnecessary jQuery call and then check it out again. Probably there are some other issues, but might be impossible to find or correct at the current state - first things first :)